# Listening current tool Changed in ArcObjects10.1?

Tags: arcobjects

I tried listening current tool changed to show current tool's message and caption in my main form. but I find esri interface about nothing.

How to listen for the current tool being changed in ArcObjects 10.1 or are there any methods I can use to get current tool?

Comment: Did you try `IApplication.CurrentTool` ?  I'm not aware of any event that fires when it changes.

Comment: IApplication.CurrentTool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000037000000 will give you the current tool as an ICommandItem. According to https://community.esri.com/thread/14567 there isn't a *current tool changed event*, or at least one that anybody knows about.